# Wordpress - Insert Image in custom form

Tags: wordpress, image, input

I have made a custom form in wordpress in the admin panel on my plugin settings page. I have an input field that I wont to hold the URL for an image that will be selected via the Wordpress Image Manager.

I am not really sure how to go about this. Is there a way to call the image manager and connect the return value to my custom input field? I do not need to upload any images ( I assume if the user wants to it will be possible after the image manager is loaded?), I just need to popup the image manager, select an image, and return the URL to be put in the input box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution for wordpress 3.5 and later:

First you need to call the function wp_enqueue_media() function in your plugin when you are loading your scripts.

Then you can follow the instruction found here:
http://mikejolley.com/2012/12/using-the-new-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-plugins/

This worked well for me!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you made your "Theme options"? If so you can call on the option with something like this.

You can call this variable at the top of the page

```
<?php
    //get theme options
    $options = get_option( 'theme_settings' ); 
?>
```

And to echo `<?php echo ($options['image_url']); ?>`

I now use an options framework called SMOF this is very handy and adds a great theme options page. https://github.com/sy4mil/Options-Framework

Comment: this is kinda overkill.. I need something that will allow me to call some javascript function that will load the native image manager in Wordpress. I see that SMOF does this, but I dont want to go dig through that code to see how they did it. I was hoping there would be some easy API call that someone knew about that I just cant seem to find.